# Universal Windows Excel-like grid with headers

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

What controls are used to create an Excel-like grid with columns with headers and the columns can be resized?

In regular WPF, it was this:

```
           <ListView>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name1}" Header="Name1"
                                Width="Auto" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

This displays Excel-like grid with one column with header and the whole column can be resized. But in Universal Windows Apps/WinRT, there is no `GridViewColumn`. How do I go about duplicating this code in Universal Windows Apps?